# failed to build some targets (01:13 (mm:ss))

Tags: android, android-source

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I'm trying to launch the AOSP build in my device but while building the AOSP , It shows the error like this, Is anyone know the solution for this ?

Error Message :

```
ninja: no work to do.
[1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
out/build-aosp_arm-cleanspec.ninja is missing, regenerating...
out/build-aosp_arm.ninja is missing, regenerating...
[25/967] including development/build/Android.mk ...
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: android_stubs_current 
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: metalava_android_stubs_current metalava_android_stubs_current
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: android_system_stubs_current 
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: android_test_stubs_current 
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: metalava_android_system_stubs_current metalava_android_system_stubs_current
development/build/build_android_stubs.mk:43: warning: metalava_android_test_stubs_current metalava_android_test_stubs_current
[567/967] including system/sepolicy/Android.mk ...
system/sepolicy/Android.mk:79: warning: BOARD_SEPOLICY_VERS not specified, assuming current platform version
[967/967] including tools/tradefederation/core/Android.mk ...
[ 99% 224/225] glob prebuilts/abi-dump...-neon/source-based/libyuv.so.lsdump.gz
[  3% 2333/77516] Yacc: ss <= external/iproute2/misc/ssfilter.y
FAILED: out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/ss_intermediates/ssfilter.c 
/bin/bash -c "prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/bison -d  --defines=out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/ss_intermediates/ssfilter.h -o out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/ss_intermediates/ssfilter.c external/iproute2/misc/ssfilter.y"
external/iproute2/misc/ssfilter.y: conflicts: 35 shift/reduce
[  3% 2340/77516] target thumb C++: sgdisk <= external/gptfdisk/gpt.cc
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
11:35:22 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (05:01 (mm:ss)) ####
```

Comment: It only means that something went wrong. You need to add the actual error message of that module.

Comment: I can't get you, Can you able to give more details ?

Comment: There should be more error messages than the one in the question title when you build.

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot, Kindly please check and let me know if anything is wrong ?

Comment: Please copy&paste the error message instead. Your problem is that the call to `bison` fails.

Comment: So what should I do now ?

Answer (score 1):

A call to `bison` fails with the error message `shift/reduce`:

```
prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/bison -d  --defines=out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/ss_intermediates/ssfilter.h -o out/target/product/generic/obj/EXECUTABLES/ss_intermediates/ssfilter.c external/iproute2/misc/ssfilter.y
```

You need to fix `external/iproute2/misc/ssfilter.y`.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Shift_002fReduce.html